# Changing element and isotope ratio ratio in material in space

Tags: material-science, metals, isotopes, cosmic-rays

Suppose we have a satellite orbiting Earth with a component made of [6061 aluminium alloy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/6061_aluminium_alloy).

Would cosmic radiation cause the element and isotope ratio of the component to change in a clearly measurable way over time? (Say, 10, 25 or 50 years)

Comment: If you're feeling bold, this is something you could answer yourself, for example by simulating high-energy protons incident on an aluminum detector in [Geant4](https://geant4.web.cern.ch)